# How to use Processing to store Arduinos serial output into a text file?

Tags: arduino, processing, android-sensors

I have been trying to store data (real time, gas sensor data) into a .txt file so as to make graphs. 
This is my arduino code:

```
const int gasPin = A0; //Gas sensor output pin to Arduino analog A0 pin
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //Initialize serial port - 9600 bps
}
void loop()
{
  Serial.println(analogRead(gasPin));
  delay(1000); // Print value every 1 sec.
}
```

And this is my Processing code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;
void setup() {
  mySerial = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
  output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.println( value );
         }
    }
}    
void keyPressed() {
    output.flush(); 
    output.close();  
    exit(); 
}
```

This doesn't work. I always get an empty data.txt file.

Comment: Processor? [tag:android-sensors]?

Comment: debug your code. can you write any text to the file from processing to the file? if yes this part is ok. can you see any output from your Arduino using a terminal program on COM3?

Answer (score 0):

You should get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then taking those steps on one at a time.

For example, can you create a simple example sketch that stores a value in a file? Don't worry about Arduino yet. Just store a single value in a file.

Then make it so you store a bunch of values in the file. Maybe the value returned from `millis()`, or the mouse position. Again, don't worry about Arduino yet. Get this working perfectly before moving on.

Separately from that, can you make an Arduino program that sends values to a Processing sketch that simply prints those values to the console?

When you have those working separately, then you can combine them into a single program.

Right now, there's no way to know which part of your code is failing: is it the Arduino code? Is it the file storage? So you need to isolate those pieces so we (you) can test them by themselves.

If you still can't figure it out, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just a single step in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.